# Highlight row in JTable

Tags: database, swing, jtable, render, highlight

I was wondering if anyone could help me. I currently have a piece of code that connects to a SQL database and have successfully displayed it in a jtable with all the buttons etc. I will soon be needing to add an external table (plain text file) to the programme.

I was thinking is there a way to highlight (in a different colour) different rows in a table only if the is a common value between them i.e. a string or int?

For example you have table A & B, both containing rows and cells, but if a common value was known, such as a "name", then the row should be highlighted in either one or both tables.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 2):

You can override [`prepareRenderer()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/javax/swing/JTable.html#prepareRenderer%28javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer,%20int,%20int%29), examine your `TableModel`, and set the color accordingly. See also this [Q&A](https://stackoverflow.com/q/8137766/230513).