# JTable renderer does not colour the cell

Tags: java, swing, jtable

[image: screenshot]

I have written a renderer and my program does not color the cell and I don't know why. When I try to color the whole row it also colors only 3 of the 7 rows. Can someone please help me?

```
public void isLow(JTable jTableBestandstabelle) {
    jTableBestandstabelle.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                JTable aTable, Object aNumberValue, boolean aIsSelected,
                boolean aHasFocus, int aRow, int aColumn
        ) {

            if (aNumberValue == null) {
                return this;
            }
            Component renderer = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    aTable, aNumberValue, aIsSelected, aHasFocus, aRow, aColumn
            );
            int m = (int) jTableBestandstabelle.getValueAt(aRow, 4);
            int a = (int) jTableBestandstabelle.getValueAt(aRow, 5);
            if (a < m && column == 5) {
                renderer.setForeground(Color.black);
                renderer.setBackground(Color.red);
            } else {
                renderer.setForeground(Color.black);
            }
            return this;
        }


    }); 
}

public void isLow(JTable jTableBestandstabelle) {
    jTableBestandstabelle.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, new DefaultTableCellRenderer() {
        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(
                JTable aTable, Object aNumberValue, boolean aIsSelected,
                boolean aHasFocus, int aRow, int aColumn
        ) {

            if (aNumberValue == null) {
                return this;
            }
            Component renderer = super.getTableCellRendererComponent(
                    aTable, aNumberValue, aIsSelected, aHasFocus, aRow, aColumn
            );
            int m = (int) jTableBestandstabelle.getValueAt(aRow, 4);
            int a = (int) jTableBestandstabelle.getValueAt(aRow, 5);
            if (a < m) {
                renderer.setForeground(Color.black);
                renderer.setBackground(Color.red);
            } else {
                renderer.setForeground(Color.black);
            }
            return this;
        }


    }); 
}
```

Comment: Maybe it should be `return renderer;` ?

Comment: no i also tried this :(

Comment: i also tried System.out.println(renderer); and as a result came 1 2 3 i think the problem is that the reenderer only get 3 rows but i dont know why

Comment: *When I try to color the whole row it also colors only 3 of the 7 rows* - probably because your columns contain different types of date (ie, not all String), so those columns will use a different renderer. To highlight an entire row based on data in the row check out: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/8137766/jtable-row-color-depending-on-value-in-model/8139123#8139123

Comment: For better help sooner, [edit] to add a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Answer (score 1):

You have two problem in your code:

1. You use a boolean columns in your table (last column). So if you want to present a checkbox in the column you cannot use a `DefaultTableCellRenderer`
2. When you use `table.setDefaultRenderer(Object.class, renderer)` this will not work for some primitive tapes like `Boolean.class` or `Integer.class` (don't know why). So you need to set the renderer for these classes too (`table.setDefaultRenderer(Integer.class, renderer)` and `table.setDefaultRenderer(Boolean.class, renderer)`). But due to the point 1 its not a good idea.

Here is mine solution:

```
import java.awt.Color;
import java.awt.Component;

import javax.swing.JFrame;
import javax.swing.JScrollPane;
import javax.swing.JTable;
import javax.swing.SwingUtilities;
import javax.swing.WindowConstants;
import javax.swing.table.DefaultTableModel;
import javax.swing.table.TableCellRenderer;
import javax.swing.table.TableColumn;

/**
 * <code>TestTable</code>.
 */
public class TestTable {

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SwingUtilities.invokeLater(new TestTable()::startUp);
    }

    private void startUp() {
        DefaultTableModel model = new DefaultTableModel(0, 7) {
            @Override
            public Class<?> getColumnClass(int columnIndex) {
                if (columnIndex == 6) {
                    return Boolean.class; // last column is boolean
                } else if (columnIndex == 0 && columnIndex > 3) {
                    return Integer.class; // 1, 4, 5 are integers
                }
                return super.getColumnClass(columnIndex);
            }
        };
        model.addRow(new Object[] {1, "Test1", "Test2", "Test3", 6, 5, false});
        model.addRow(new Object[] {1, "Test11", "Test22", "Test33", 4, 5, true});
        JTable table = new JTable(model);
        for (int i = 0; i < table.getColumnCount(); i++) {
            TableColumn col = table.getColumnModel().getColumn(i);
            int modelCol = table.convertColumnIndexToModel(i);
            col.setCellRenderer(new MyCellRenderer(table.getDefaultRenderer(model.getColumnClass(modelCol))));
        }
        JFrame frm = new JFrame("Table test");
        frm.add(new JScrollPane(table));
        frm.setDefaultCloseOperation(WindowConstants.DISPOSE_ON_CLOSE);
        frm.pack();
        frm.setLocationRelativeTo(null);
        frm.setVisible(true);
    }

    private static class MyCellRenderer implements TableCellRenderer {
        private final TableCellRenderer origin;

        public MyCellRenderer(TableCellRenderer origin) {
            this.origin = origin;
        }

        @Override
        public Component getTableCellRendererComponent(JTable table, Object value, boolean isSelected, boolean hasFocus, int row,
                int column) {
            Component c = origin.getTableCellRendererComponent(table, value, isSelected, hasFocus, row, column);
            int m = (int) table.getValueAt(row, 4);
            int a = (int) table.getValueAt(row, 5);
            if (a < m) {
                c.setForeground(Color.black);
                c.setBackground(Color.red);
            } else {
                c.setForeground(Color.black);
                c.setBackground(Color.white);
            }
            return c;
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: *don't know why* - because Swing provides default renderers for those data types. The `Object` renderer is only used if a data type does not have a default renderer.

Comment: Note the `&&` should be `||` in the `getColumnClass(...)` method. Also, the renderer doesn't work if the columns are reordered. The logic in the renderer needs to use the `convertColumnIndexToModel(...)` method.

Comment: Thank you very much now i understand it